# How can I add an onclick event to an HTMLAnchorElement?

Tags: typescript, anchor, ionic4

I'm working on an ionic app. As a part of this app, I'm sending a get request and get an html page. Now, I need to present it in my app. I've tried to present it in an iframe using the srcdoc but the web page has links to another pages and when it is being clicked I need to provide an Authorization header. Therefore I decided I should take the html string and manipulate it so when the anchor is being clicked it will call a function and send a get request with the authorization head (to the href url)

I'm converting my html string to a Document object and get all the "a" items:

```
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(this.htmlPage, "text/html");
var links = doc.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      const element = links.item(i);
      var self = this;
      element.onclick = function() {
        self.redirect(element.href);
      };
      element.removeAttribute("href");
    }
```

The href attribute is being removed but the onclick event is not added. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
Just did:

```
element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.redirect(element.href);
  });
```

and then added to the page by calling:

```
this.webview.nativeElement.appendChild(doc.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
  <a (click)="myFunction()"></a>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Because it’s an HTMLAnchorElement I can’t just add it. I have tried using element.addAttribute(“(click)”, “this.redirect()”); but it said the it contains illegal characters. How do I do it using typescript?